# In Sage, how to look at orbits of conjugation in GL(2,q). Actually, their image in PGL(2,q)?

Tags: math-software, sagemath

I have a matrix $A$ in $\text{GL}(2,q)$ or order $m$.

The cyclic group of order $m$ acts upon $\text{GL}(2,q)$ by conjugation powers of $A$ (choose a generator of the cyclic group to act by conjugation by $A$).

I would like to see the orbits of this action. How can this be done in Sage?
(I want to see matrices, not permutations).